# Short horizontal and vertical bar of same length in math

Tags: math-mode, amssymb

I want to mark a variable *I* with a short vertical or horizontal bar in order to relate it to something being vertical or horizontal in real life. For the vertical line, `$I^\shortmid$` (from `amssymb`) is looking very nicely, but I can't produce a horizontal line of equal length. I tried `$I^{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\shortmid$}}$`, however this makes the bar longer for reasons I don't understand:

[image: unequally long bars]

Taking a different symbol like `I^-` and `I^\text{-}` produces ugly results as well. Can someone please explain what is happening inside the `\rotatebox` and suggest a fix? I will also appreciate any alternative markup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to take care of the current math style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}

\newcommand{\vrt}{\shortmid}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\hrz}{{\mathpalette\hrz@\relax}}
\newcommand{\hrz@}[2]{%
  \mspace{-1mu}%
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\m@th#1\,\vrt$}%
  \mspace{-1mu}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$I^\hrz I^\vrt$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The reason why the rotated `\shortmid` seems larger is because the default math size setting within `\rotatebox` would be `\textstyle`, while it should be `\scripstyle` if you're using it in a superscript.

You could try with the following definitions of `\vertical` and `\horizontal`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx}

\newcommand{\horizontal}[1]{%
  #1^{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\scriptstyle\shortmid$}}
}
\newcommand{\vertical}[1]{%
  #1^{\shortmid}
}

\begin{document}

$\vertical{I}\ \horizontal{I}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, now I understand what's going on. However, because @egreg proposed a more general solution and also took care of positioning, I accepted his answer.

Comment: @Eldrad: Yes, that's great. I just answered the question. He went the extra mile.

Answer (score 3):

Preserves the proper math style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx,scalerel}
\newcommand{\vrt}{\shortmid}
\newcommand{\hrz}{{\ThisStyle{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\SavedStyle\vrt$}}}}
\begin{document}
$I^\hrz I^\vrt$

$\scriptstyle I^\hrz I^\vrt$
\end{document}
```

[image]